# Can someone explain the RelativeOrAbsolute parameter in overloaded version of URI class?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows-phone-8, .net-framework-version

The following code assigns the `Microphone.png` image to image of button but I failed to understand the role of `relative` parameter in overloaded version of `Uri` class.

```
RecordButton.IconUri = new Uri(
    "/Assets/AppBar/microphone.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemple :
Relative => You should be in the same folder. 
Folder 1 contains one page " page 1 " and an image "X"
Folder 2 contains one page " page 2 "

You are in the page 2 and you write =>

```
<image source="X.png" />
```

You can't do this because you are not in the correct folder but you can write "/Folder1/X.png"  or "../Folder1/X.png".

Absolute => Full path like http://Abundantcode.com/image.jpg

For windows phone developpement, you have uriking.relativeorabsolute property :D

Answer (score 1):

URIKind.Relative means that you don't have a full path to the file. Absolute means that you will specify full path to the file.

Comment: +1 Right but it doesn't add much to what MSDN says, maybe few examples may help...

Answer (score 0):

I've used relative Uris with the Uri constructor

```
public Uri(
    Uri baseUri,
    Uri relativeUri
)
```

to create a fully pathed URI.  There are some advantages in reducing storage overhead and you can interchange the baseUri even across protocols if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URIs are characterized by a complete reference to the resource

```
example: http://www.contoso.com/index.html
```

While a relative Uri depends on a previously defined base URI

```
example: /index.html
```

Check out this [UriKind.Relative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)